# Excel formula (Avg the difference)

Tags: excel, formula, average

I have an excel file with 5 columns Year1%,Year2,Year3%, and I added the the 4th column to get the avg for each day for all 3 years, now I need to find formula to avg the difference between each day in year1 and the Avg, year2 and the Avg, and Year3 and the Avg,this is how my columns look like:

```
   Year1 % _ Year2% _ Year3% _ Avg% _ Avg Diff to %
```

Day 1
Day 2
...

[image: IMG]

Comment: A bit more info would be useful, can you edit your question to include sample data and expected result?

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yet? What's attempt looking like?

Comment: Just added an image of my column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table starts in A1, this formulas goes into the first row of the 5th data column (F2) to give you the average "DIFFERENCE" from the average:

```
=AVERAGE(E2-B2:D2)
```

This is an array formula that must be saved by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Note that this will always equal 0 (maybe showing rounding error due to Excel working with floating point precision)

This is due to the definition of the average being the point that is, on average, the same distance from all other points. The positive and negative differences all sum to zero.

If, however, you wanted the average "DISTANCE" from the average (taking only the magnitude of the difference), you would use this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(ABS(E2-B2:D2))
```

This is also an array formula.

Statistically, this is not an effective measure of the spread of data. A more effective measure comes from squaring the difference rather than taking the absolute value:

```
=AVERAGE((E2-B2:D2)^2)
```

But this is actually just the variance:

```
=VAR.P(B2:D2)
```

The square root of which is the Standard Deviation:

```
=STDEV.P(B2:D2)
```